# No such file or directory: 'profile_pics/img.jpg'

Tags: django

When a user attempts to upload a profile picture this error is displayed. However the image is successfully uploaded to the database and displayed in the app. I believe the error is something to do with the redirection after the form submits but I couldn't figure it out. I recently set my app up with aws s3 buckets so that might also have something to do with it but the images are successfully uploaded and pulled from the bucket so likely un related.

[image]
[image]

view:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.name)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Update Profile</legend>
        {{ p_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="action-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: let remove your `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` and see what happens? I think the error coming from your `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: @boyenec you are right! I removed it and the image upload works fine now. However i still would like to resize the images. Any idea what the issue is? I am assuming now its the `img = Image.open(self.image.name)` indicated in the stack trace

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for resize or compress image.

```
def compress(image):
                im = Image.open(image)
                out_put_size = (300,300)
                im.thumbnail(out_put_size)
                # create a BytesIO object
                im_io = BytesIO() 
                # save image to BytesIO object
                im = im.resize([500,500])
                #resize image
                im = im.convert("RGB")
                im = im.save(im_io,'JPEG', quality=50) 
                # create a django-friendly Files object
                new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
                return new_image

class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      #image compression start
      if self.image:
         # call the compress function
         new_image = compress(self.image)
         # set self.image to new_image
         self.image = new_image
      #image compression end 
      super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!